# Return value of pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question regarding pointers to pointers.

Lets assume I have a `class foo`.
And I create a pointer of a pointer to this class somewhere in my code.

```cpp
foo** x;
```

What would be the return value if I make a function which returns `foo**` as well?

```cpp
foo** bar();
```

I also have an array of pointers and I want to return this array in an accessor function as a pointer-to-pointer-to a class.

Comment: Where is foo* ?

Comment: Umm, if the function returns `foo**`, then the return value will be a `foo**`. Perhaps you can clarify that a bit? Also - if you have that array outside the accessor function, why does it need to return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the return value if I make a foo** foo(); function?

It would be the address of an object of type `foo*` (or a pointer-interconverible type). Or it could be null, or an invalid pointer value (but you should avoid the latter).

Note that calling this a "double pointer" is confusing since double is a type, so one might understand that you meant `double*`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the question is about shared names or double pointers, but if such is possible, you can declare allocate space for a foo object and return that address/pointer(variable).

Does it really have to be a double pointer though? You can make a pointer to an allocated pointer, but that would have no point. On the other hand, you can allocate an array and return it's address to have a double pointer.

That's all I can tell :/

Comment: Yeah actually I have an array of pointers and this array I wanna return in a Getter function as a double pointer, which points to a class..I hope it is understandable

Comment: @eagle_master Consider using std::array or std::vector to get rid of a plain array. Apart from being a lot safer to use it would also get rid of the awkward doubled pointer.